# Writing a sample virus (not harmful)

Tags: linux, virus

*I don't know if such a question is allowed on this site, sorry if it's not*

For educational purposes I am asked to write a small virus running on Linux, which should just be able to inject itself into other binaries (but not anything else).
I thought of injecting its code with a technique described here: http://www.securelist.com/en/weblog?weblogid=183651915 and [this one](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://dirkgerrits.com/wp-content/uploads/elf-virus.pdf&ei=qTI5T7q1CdG1hAffl_XNCQ&usg=AFQjCNHkavg72f-qSsnfXUnjqdbhOWVcew) (playing with the ELF format) but I couldn't find the assembly source. Do you have any links showing how to do such things? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's sample code for run-time process injection on linux. This is how meterpreter does it.[LibHiJack](https://github.com/lattera/libhijack)

Answer (score 2):

You can probably write one using Alexander Bartolich's [ELF Virus Writing How-To](http://virus.bartolich.at/virus-writing-HOWTO/_html/index.html)

A fellow by the name of Silvio Cesare had a Unix Virus mailing list in the mid-90s. Search for his name and "unix virus" and you'll find goodies like [this](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hh/virus/unix-viruses.txt).

You could also benefit from Tom Duff's [Viral Attacks on Unix System Security](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/tdvirus.pdf) .  He gives an example sh-script virus, but I think you could transliterate that code to C and have a working virus.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @BruceEdiger's excellent answer, you might enjoy the following paper: [Hunting for metamorphic](http://crypto.stanford.edu/cs155old/cs155-spring11/papers/viruses.pdf).